# Cancelled SQL Server delete statement in the middle of running on server

Tags: sql-server-2008

A delete statement was accidentally ran, but cancelled within a few seconds by a programmer in sql server management studio.  Is it possible to know what records were deleted and to recover them?  This is for sql server 2008.

Comment: If it was cancelled successfully, no rows should have been deleted. If it completed before it was cancelled, all rows that match the where/join clauses (assuming there was one, otherwise all rows in the table) should have been deleted. A SQL statement is an implicit transaction, so it is either all or nothing - there is no possible way that half the rows were deleted.

Comment: I was able to confirm what you said by putting the large table on my local database and then try deleting it and then cancelling it before it finished.  I checked and I received the same record count after cancelling a delete that didn't finish as I did before I ran the delete statement.  This is good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Contact your dba, to recover the data. You can see the last executed queries, but you will need elevated access to run this statement:

```
SELECT  O.Name, o.type_desc, ps.last_execution_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS PS
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(PS.sql_handle) t
INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules as M 
ON M.object_id = t.objectid
INNER JOIN sys.objects as O 
ON M.object_id = o.object_id 
order by ps.last_execution_time desc;
```

You can also try to look for it in the cache using this: `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans`

Comment: This query doesn't have anything at all to do with the data, it just identifies a bunch of recent queries that were run on the system. It sounds like the OP already knows exactly what statement was executed.